# AutoMapper Profiles and Unit Testing

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nunit, ninject, automapper

I'm rolling over my AutoMappers from using one large AutoMapperConfiguration class to using actual profiles. Global now looks like so (forgive the Open/Close violation for now)

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
                       {
                          x.AddProfile<ABCMappingProfile>();
                          x.AddProfile<XYZMappingProfile>();
                          // etc., etc.
                  });
```

The key piece that got me over the top and the hurdle that had previously always stopped me from using profiles was my ninject binding. I could never get the binding to work.
Prior I had this binding:

```
Bind<IMappingEngine>().ToConstant(Mapper.Engine).InSingletonScope();
```

I've since migrated to this binding:

```
Bind<IMappingEngine>().ToMethod(context => Mapper.Engine);
```

This now works, the app is functional, I have profiles, and things are good.

The hitch is now in my unit tests. Using NUnit, I'd setup my constructor dependencies.

```
private readonly IMappingEngine _mappingEngine = Mapper.Engine;
```

and then in my [Setup] method I'd construct my MVC controller and call the AutoMapperConfiguration class.

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _apiController = new ApiController(_mappingEngine);
    AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
}
```

which I've now modified to.

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _apiController = new ApiController(_mappingEngine);

    Mapper.Initialize(x =>
                          {
                              x.AddProfile<ABCMappingProfile>();
                              x.AddProfile<XYZMappingProfile>();
                              // etc., etc.
                          });
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. The mappings do not appear to be getting picked up as when I hit a method that uses mappings, AutoMapper throws an exception stating the mapping doesn't exist. Any suggestions on how/what to change the the mapper definition/injection in the test to resolve this? I'm guessing the definition of the IMappingEngine field is my problem but unsure of what options I have.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Issue that you have is result of using static `Mapper.Engine` which is some kind of singleton that contains configuration for AutoMapper. By convention, *`Mapper.Engine` should not be changed after it has been configured*. So, if you'd like to configure Automapper by providing `AutoMapper.Profiler` for each of unittest, you should avoid using it.

Changes are quite simple: add to instance your class `AutoMapperConfiguration` it's own instance `AutoMapper.MappingEngine` instead of using global static `Mapper.Engine`.

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration 
{
    private volatile bool _isMappinginitialized;
    // now AutoMapperConfiguration  contains its own engine instance
    private MappingEngine _mappingEngine;

    private void Configure()
    {
        var configStore = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers());

        configStore.AddProfile(new ABCMappingProfile());
        configStore.AddProfile(new XYZMappingProfile());

        _mappingEngine = new MappingEngine(configStore);

        _isMappinginitialized = true;
    }

    /* other methods */
}
```

ps: [full sample is here](https://gist.github.com/akimboyko/5449531)

Comment: Sorry I haven't gotten back to you yet. I ran a test and your Git does function, but as soon as I try to pull the engine out as a constructor parameter things go off the rails. I'll circle back around tonight for further testing.

Comment: I've verified this morning that as a stand alone solution, your git does what you'd expect. However, for my scenario where I'm trying to pass an instance of IMappingEngine as a constructor parameter utilizing Ninject, I'm still not receiving initialized mappings. I took the git, and added a method to return out the initialized MappingEngine and attempted to pass that as a constructor param. The results were the same.

Comment: Have you tried to replace _all_ calls/refences to `Mapper` (`Mapper.Initialize`, `Mapper.Engine`, etc) with new stand-alone instance of `MappingEngine`?

Comment: thanks for this code sample, I was able to use this in my tests to test each individual mapping profile without referencing the static Mapper